# 1300, 'Invalid utf8 character string during load file that is preprocessed in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-unicode

I'm loading xml data in Python, pulling out the parts I wants, dumping them into delimited files, then reading them into mysql using a load data command.

The following are the relevant encoding handling points (I think), for reference, but I'm pretty sure the problem is due to an incorrect unicode entry that Python and mysql handle differently (more on that below after the bits of code -- which again, I don't think are relevant ...).

**Edit:** The code was relevant. It was a mistake in the code, although you may be interested in learning that unicode has characters that are for private use (linked below)

Opening the xml file:

```
from lxml import etree
import gzip

        doc = etree.iterparse(gzip.GzipFile(xmlfile), events=('start', 'end'),encoding="utf-8")
```

Opening the delimited file to write to from the processed xml

```
#Oops, just noticed the quote all here, may not keep that
        self.filename = filename
        self.fp = open(self.filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.fp, 
                                 delimiter='\t', 
                                 quotechar='"', 
                                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, 
                                 lineterminator='\n')
```

Creating the SQL table

```
import pymysql

#connection code ... pymysql.connect() -> connection.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE abstract (" + 
                     "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY," + 
                     "pmid INT NOT NULL," +
                     "element_id INT," +
                     "label varchar(100)," +
                     "category varchar(15)," +
                     "abstract TEXT," + 
                     "FOREIGN KEY (pmid) " +
                     "REFERENCES main (pmid) " +
                     "ON DELETE CASCADE " +
                     ") CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
```

The code that fails to load the table

```
        tsv_path = root_path + name_root + '_' + table_name + '.tsv'
        mycursor.execute(
            "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %s " +
            "INTO TABLE " + table_name + ' '
            "CHARACTER SET UTF8 " +
            "FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' " +
            "TERMINATED BY '\t' " +
            "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'",(tsv_path,))
```

So, everything seems to work well except for an entry that contains this bit of xml:
`\n&#1048596;&#1048600;&#1048601`

Using this wonderful website, https://unicodelookup.com/#1048600/1,  I find out that these unicode values are part of "Supplementary Private Use Area-B" and for private use only (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). Python doesn't seem to mind them but mysql does.

So, onto my question. I'm dealing with tens of millions of data entries. I'd like something that fixes this problem with little computational effort. I don't want to run every character through an extensive check in Python (where extensive means computationally expensive and is clearly relative). I do want to keep the entry, just remove or replace the offending characters. I'm not sure if this is something I can/should handle in Python or mysql. How do I go about cleaning the strings so that mysql doesn't complain?

Comment: Those characters require 4 bytes in UTF8.  Your table will handle it (utf8mb4 means 4 bytes), but your `LOAD FILE` specifies `UTF8`, which is limited to 3 bytes.  Try using `UTF8MB4` in your `LOAD FILE`.

Comment: Well I feel silly. I think if it had been a clear character like a math symbol or emoji I would have looked at my code again. I also saw someone else say something that sql and python have different considerations on what makes valid unicode which I think also through me off (not sure if that is actually true).

Comment: Also, just to be clear, the solution suggested by Tim fixes the problem.